# WSO2 API Manager can't call a registered external API. It could be related to a proxy configuration problem?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am facing the following problem with an installation of WSO2 API Manager.

I register two APIs: the first one is the PizzaShack example API provided with the product that run on the same machine. It works fine.

The second one is an external API that I have registered using the publisher tool. The problem is that when I try to call this external API using the store I obtain the following error message as response:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>101500</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Error in Sender</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

I suppose (but I am absolutly not sure of this) that the problem could be related to the following situation: the machine on which WSO2 API Manager is installed use a proxy to be exposed on the Internet. So I think that this proxy have also to be set on WSO2 API Manager in some way.

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something? It could be the cause of my problem?

Comment: Do you see errors in wso2carbon.log file ? It is located in repository/logs directory

Comment: If you use curl to invoke the external API directly from the machine APIM is installed, does that work?